# geom_raster gives "stripy" results

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I am trying to create a raster plot with ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
freqData <- data.frame(cells = rep(1:27, each = 101),
                       frequency = rep(1/seq(1, 1001, 10), 27),
                       power = rnorm(101*27))
```

Now, when I do

```
ggplot(freqData, aes(frequency, cells)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = power), interpolate = T)
```

I get this

[image: raster plot]

Interestingly, zooming in shows this:

[image: zoom in]

If I try and define frequency as `seq(1, 1001, 10)` (i.e. without 1/) then everything works as expected.

I am probably missing something really obvious here, can anyone help?

Comment: maybe plot against 1/frequency

Comment: @RichardTelford yes, as mentioned I can easily plot against period... but I wanted to produce a frequency graph! :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the interpolation only works within a local region.
Vertical lines here are the x points we have. I think raster's main use is for equally spaced x & y data points like the example in https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html which has the same difference in the x axis. Your's is a really extreme case as 1/(1,10,20)... quickly converges to 0

```
dt <- expand.grid(x=c(.01,.05,.15,.5,1),
                  y=seq(0,5,.1))
dt$power <- rnorm(1:nrow(dt))

ggplot(dt, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill = power), interpolate = T) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = unique(dt$x))
```

Sorry can't provide a solution with this, other than try to use equally spaced data... hopefully someone has a better answer :)

Comment: Thank you, Jonny. I thought that was the issue, hopefully, someone can point to an alternative...